# selecting records based on datetimepicker control

Tags: vb6

I am using vb6 (and MSAccess on backend) and created a form containing one dtpicker control, one button and two textboxes. And on database side, there is a table with `id` as number and `dt` defined as datetime columns.

Now I want to select record based on date and display id on one textbox and date on another.

What I did on button click is:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Set rs = con.Execute("Select * from table1 Where DateValue(dt) =#" & DateValue(DTPicker1.Value) & "#")
    Text1.Text = rs("id")
    Text2.Text = rs("dtpicker1")
End Sub
```

Which displays id correctly but not showing date and an error is raised "item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal".

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Change `rs("dtpicker1")` to `rs("dt")`

```
Private Sub Command1_Click() 
    Set rs = con.Execute("Select * from table1 Where DateValue(dt) =#" & DateValue(DTPicker1.Value) & "#") 
    Text1.Text = rs("id") 
    'Text2.Text = rs("dtpicker1") ' old/bad code
    Text2.Text = rs("dt")         ' new/good code
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
Dim intYear As Integer
Dim intMonth As Integer
Dim intDay As Integer
intYear = Year(TextBox1.Value)
intMonth = Month(TextBox1.Value)
intDay = Day(TextBox1.Value)`enter code here`
Date = DateSerial(intYear, intMonth, intDay)
End Sub
```

Comment: You might want to add some explanation to your code.